# What do you call the first column of a .NET WinForms GridView?

Tags: c#, gridview

What do you call the first column in a GridView?  This is the leftmost non-databound column.  Is it possible to prevent this column from being rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about the column of row headers.  If so, set the [RowHeadersVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheadersvisible.aspx) to false.